# Proving something is a proper subset (Hints no solutions please)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Please DO NOT provide the full solution.**

Prove that {$10k+7 | k \in\mathbb{Z}$} is a proper subset of {$5m-8|m\in\mathbb{Z}$}

I can see this is indeed true $\{\ldots, 7, 17, 27,\ldots\} \subset \{\ldots, 2, 7, 12, 17, 22, 27, \ldots\}.\,$ As for a proper subset, there is an element in the second set not contained in the first set.

How would I prove this? Unfortunately I have not progressed yet. Any small hints to start me off? I assume you have to manipulate the first one to arrive to the second one?

Also, is there a standard approach to tackle these questions?

Comment: For $10k+7$, find an $m$ such that $10k+7 = 5m-8$.

Comment: $M = \frac{10k+15}{5} = 2k+3$?

Comment: @Bobby Is this in $\mathbb{Z}$? Can you then conclude whether this same number, $10k + 7$, is in $\{5m-8 | m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** We need only find $m$ so that $10k + 7 = 5m - 8 \iff 10 k = 5m - 15$.

**Alternate hint:** Note that $5m - 8 = 5m - 15 + 7 = 5(m - 3) + 7$, and recall that $m \in \mathbb Z$

Comment: $M = \frac{10k+15}{5} = 2k+3$? But I don't see how this is relevant. Maybe its late.

Comment: @amWhy: needs another TU! =1

Comment: @Bobby because you got $m=2k+3$ it means that when you choose some $k$ then the number $10k+7$ is the same as the number $5(2k+3)-8$ so that for every $k$ there is a $m$ such that $10k+7=5m-8$(there is the relevance). It is a special case of the linear diophantine equation, hopefully amWhy will not get mad because i am intruder on her answer. ;)

Comment: Not "mad" at all, @Amateur. Your comment is helpful, and so you are hardly an intruder! ;-)

Comment: @Amzoti: What is a TU?

Comment: @celtschk: A "TU" means a "thumb's up", which here, usually means clicking on the $\uparrow$: an "upvote".

Answer (score 5):

You need to show that it is a **subset**, that is the element $10k+7$ with arbitrary $k\in \mathbb Z$ must be writable as an element $5m-8$, that is for each $k$ you must be able to specify an $m$ with $10k+7=5m-8$.

Also, you need to show that the subset is **proper**, that is you must exhibit at least one element $5m-8$ that *cannot* be written as $10k+7$.